# How to set page size when using WinSpool

Tags: c#, winapi, printing

I am using Winspool API to print to a thermal printer. That printer accepts ESC/POS commands so some settings I am sending to the printer that way, instead of using Winspool.

Printing works OK, but some printer drivers print perfectly one page, however, other don't.

All windows printer drivers don't allow to set a custom page size, in my case, it is about 50 mm.

These are the steps I am doing:

1- I initialize the printer:

```
_printer.SendBytesToPrinter(new byte[] { EscPos.ESC, EscPos.INIT });
```

where `_printer` is a helper class that encapsulates native methods call for the Winspool API, and EscPos constants are the bytes corresponding to the ESC/POS Epson standard commands (this works, because when I use direct USB or RS232 communication, it works OK).

`SendBytesToPrinter` is:

```
    public bool SendBytesToPrinter(byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (this.PrinterIsOpened)
        {
            IntPtr pBytes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pBytes, bytes.Length);
            int dwCount = bytes.Length;
            try
            {
                return NativeMethods.WritePrinter(_hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out int dwWritten);
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pBytes);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

2- I create the document:

```
_printer.CreateDocument("DocName");
```

Where `CreateDocument` is:

```
    public bool CreateDocument(string name)
    {
        if (this.PrinterIsOpened)
        {
            _di.pDocName = name;
            _di.pDataType = "RAW";
            //_di.pDataType = "XPS_PASS";
            if (NativeMethods.StartDocPrinter(_hPrinter, 1, _di))
            {
                if (NativeMethods.StartPagePrinter(_hPrinter))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

3- Set the character font:

```
                int font = fontType + 16 * size;
                if (emphasized)
                    font += 8;
                _printer.SendBytesToPrinter(new byte[] { EscPos.ESC, EscPos.MODE, (byte)font });
```

4- Set the paper size (or at least, an atempt to set the paper size):

```
        int x = Helpers.Coordinates.GetLeftMarginFromMM(leftMargin);
        int y = Helpers.Coordinates.GetHeightFromMM(height);
        if (_printer.SendBytesToPrinter(new byte[] { EscPos.ESC, EscPos.ESC_PAGE_MODE }))
                {
                    // Set horizontal and vertical motion units, x = 180, y = 255
                    if (_printer.SendBytesToPrinter(new byte[] { EscPos.GS, EscPos.GS_MOTION_UNITS, Helpers.Coordinates.X_MOTION_UNITS, Helpers.Coordinates.Y_MOTION_UNITS }))
                    {
                        // ESC W xL xH yL yH dxL dxH dyL dyH
                        if (width == 1)    // 58 mm
                            return _printer.SendBytesToPrinter(new byte[] { EscPos.ESC, EscPos.PRINTING_AREA, (byte)(x & 0xFF) /*xL*/, (byte)(x >> 8) /*xH*/, 0 /*yL*/, 0 /*yH*/, 154 /*dxL*/, 1 /*dxH*/, (byte)(y & 0xFF) /*dyL*/, (byte)(y >> 8) /*dyH*/ });
                        else               // 80 mm
                            return _printer.SendBytesToPrinter(new byte[] { EscPos.ESC, EscPos.PRINTING_AREA, (byte)(x & 0xFF) /*xL*/, (byte)(x >> 8) /*xH*/, 0 /*yL*/, 0 /*yH*/, 55 /*dxL*/, 2 /*dxH*/, (byte)(y & 0xFF) /*dyL*/, (byte)(y >> 8) /*dyH*/ });
                    }
                }
```

5- Print the lines:

```
                int totalBytes = 0;

                List<byte> data = new List<byte>(256);
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    data.Clear();
                    data.AddRange(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(line));
                    data.Add(EscPos.LF);
                    totalBytes += data.Count;

                    _printer.SendBytesToPrinter(data.ToArray());
                }
```

6- Cut the paper:

```
_printer.SendBytesToPrinter(new byte[] { EscPos.GS, EscPos.CUT, 1 });
```

7- Close the document:

```
_printer.CloseDocument();
```

where `CloseDocument` is:

```
    public void CloseDocument()
    {
        NativeMethods.EndPagePrinter(_hPrinter);
        NativeMethods.EndDocPrinter(_hPrinter);
    }
```

All works correcly but setting the page size.

I have read about seting the DevMode in some way, but I don't know how to set the custom page size there.

Any help, please?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Using both the spooler and raw print commands doesn't make sense and can't come to a good end.  A "page mode" makes little sense if you send a cut command.

Comment: @HansPassant so, how to do that without using raw commands?